# Is it possible to add logs in a setup script?

Tags: setup-script, logging

I'm trying to add some alerts in system.log if my setup script cannot run properly (the sql query needs a SUPER user to run properly).
I'm not able to write any log in this setup script.

Is it possible ? If yes, what did I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forcing the log.

```
Mage::log($message, null, 'system.log', true);
```

Comment: I'll give you feedback ASAP